# JavaScript Animated placeholder doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to write a code that changes placeholder every 2seconds. Also, it's thought to type letter by letter, and also erase one by one.

Unfortunetely, it isn't working.

I'm new to JS, coming from Python, so maybe I'm missing something very simple.

```
// Espera o HTML da página carregar

$(document).ready(function(){

    // Frases que aparecerão
    var phrases = ['Investir em ações', 'Tesouro-Direto', 'Valuation', 'Dados LREN3'];
    // Index da frase que será exibida
    var index = 0;
    // Tamanho da array
    var length = phrases.length;

    // Função que vai exibir as frases a cada intervalo de tempo
    setInterval(function(){

        // Verifica se o índice não é maior que o tamanho da array
        if (index < length){

            // Frase que será escrita
            var newPlaceholder = phrases[index];

            // Tamanho da frase que será escrita
            var txtLen = newPlaceholder.length;

            // Caracter pelo qual a frase vai começar a ser escrita
            var char = 0;

            // Inicializa a variável que vai receber a função timeout
            var timeout;

            // Função que digita a frase letra por letra
            function typeIt(){

                // Tempo que vai demorar até a próxima letra ser escrita
                var humanize = Math.round(Math.random() * (200 - 30) + 30);

                // Executa a função depois de alguns segundos (humanize)
                timeout = setTimeout(function(){

                    // Deve estar sempre um caracter a frente por conta do slice
                    char++;

                    // Parte da string que será digitada
                    var substr = newPlaceholder.substring(0, char);

                    // Digita a parte da string
                    $('input').attr('placeholder', substr + "|");

                    // Executa a função type
                    typeIt();

                    // Caso já tenha chegado ao fim da string
                    if (char === txtLen) {
                        $('input').attr('placeholder', $('input').attr('placeholder').slice(0, -1));
                        clearTimeout(timeout);
                    }
                }, humanize);
            }
            index++;
        }
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: Have you checked the browser's console for errors? Post a [mcve] please

Comment: Yeah, I've checked. No errors. I'm sorry, this is the complete code: http://jsfiddle.net/oedLwmn5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never initiate your series of typing. You should call `typeIt();` as the last line of your `setInterval()` callback.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just one more thing, if you could help me, of course. I've find the timeout piece of code somewhere in Internet. Is there any sense calling "typeIt()" inside of it?